# angular 2 delete row from table when confirm button is clicked on modal

Tags: angular

I am using the following function in component to remove a row from table when delete button is clicked

```
remove(item) {

   this.data.splice(this.data.indexOf(item),1);        
}
```

and then call this function in template inside the delete button to delete the row.This works. But rather then deleting the row when delete button is clicked, I want to delete the row when user clicks the confirm button in bootstrap modal. When remove function in modal confirm button is called it then always delete the last row from the table. How can i achieve this? to only remove the row when modal confirm button is clicked rather than actual delete button is clicked

below item is resident

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let resident of mf.data">
    <td>{{resident.res_firstname}}</td>
    <td>{{resident.res_surname}}</td>
    <td>{{resident.res_homePhone}}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{resident.res_DoB}}</td>
    <td>{{resident.res_City | uppercase}}</td>
    <td><a class="btn mini red-stripe" href="{site_url()}admin/editFront/2">Edit</a></td>

    <td><a class="confirm-delete btn mini red-stripe " style="color:red; font-size : 16px" role="button" data-title="kitty" data-id="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Delete this entry</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> Are you sure you want to delete this Record?</div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer ">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="remove(resident)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Yes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> No</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: Then bind the above `remove` function (with argument) to the confirm button. Or set the item varaible on clicking the delete button `this.item = item;` then call `remove` function without argument. Finally delete  `this.item` from the remove func

Comment: call the same method via passing the same item as an argument.

Comment: When I bind the remove function to confirm button then it only delete the last row from the table. I am passing the item argument in ngfor loop

Comment: Your resident must be the one selected. Maybe you can have a select in your table that have a click-event on it. in your code, you can save the selected resident by doing a `this.selcetedResident = clickedResident`, and then in your remove callback, you do a remove index of selectedResident